# Ruby: Sum of "first element" in each array

Tags: ruby

If I have a hash that looks like this:

```
C = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 
     [1, 2, 1, 1], 
     [1, 3, 1, 7], 
     [1, 1, 4, 1]]
```

What is a fast way to sum the columns and produce the following result:

```
C = [4, 7, 7, 10]
```

Edit: The way I was doing it coming from a C background was to parse thru the result and summing manually, that's why I asked. didn't know where else to look for.

Comment: which version of ruby are you using ?

Comment: 2.0 ... why -2 I don't get it?

Comment: Are they always gonna be 4x4 matrixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 
     [1, 2, 1, 1], 
     [1, 3, 1, 7], 
     [1, 1, 4, 1]]
arr.transpose.map{|e| e.inject(:+)}
# => [4, 7, 7, 10]
```

Comment: Downvote was probably just a misclick.